# Different definitions of Ext groups

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

I am reading on derived categories and am given the definition $\operatorname{Ext} _\mathcal{A}^k\left( {M,N} \right) = {\operatorname{Hom} _{\operatorname{D} \left( \mathcal{A} \right)}}\left( {M,N\left[ k \right]} \right)$.

However I am more familiar with the definition $\operatorname{Ext} _\mathcal{A}^k\left( {M,N} \right) = \left( {{R^k}{{\operatorname{Hom} }_\mathcal{A}}\left( {M, - } \right)} \right)\left( N \right)$.

How can I show that these are the same?

Comment: Isomorphism between $RHom$ and Yoneda $ext$ is well known. Then, from any length $k+2$ exact sequence going from $M$ to $N$, i. e. zero object in derived category representing element of Yoneda $ext^k(M, N)$ you can remove $M$: it'll be object of derived category representing $M$, and identity morphism on $N$ side is in your derived $Hom$. Checking that this gives an isomorphism is pretty easy.

Comment: Found a proof in Huybrechts book. Proposition 2.56.